# É possível fazer isso com table td?

Tags: javascript, html, css, table, media-queries

Ok vejamos:

```
//PHONE
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>COL 1</td>
        <td>COL 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>COL 1</td>
        <td>COL 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

//TABLET E MAIORES
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) { table>tr>td {...} }
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) { table>tr>td {...} }
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>COL 1</td>
        <td>COL 2</td>            
        <td>COL 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>COL 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

É possível fazer isto? Quando estiver no celular uma tr com duas td, em tablets começam a ter uma tr com 3 td depois com 4 e assim por diante...

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar o `nth-child` para esconder as colunas. Seria algo assim:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    table td:nth-child(n+3) {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    table td:nth-child(n+4) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/x6rckfsp/

Answer (score 0):

@media não pode alterar a codificação HTML, apenas o estilo de cada elemento HTML.

Interessante seria vc usar div com porcentagens.

Comment: Concordo que não pode alterar o HTML mas pode esconder/mostrar certo?

Comment: Certo, mas esconder/mostrar não vai resolver seu problema. Certo seriam divs com porcentagens para cada dispositivo/tamanho de tela.

Comment: Sim verdade, mas com `table{ width: 100%;}` parece funcionar bem: http://jsfiddle.net/x6rckfsp/1/

Comment: Então. Pela dúvida dele, seria normal: width:50% e com as media query ficariam com width: 33%. A dúvida é posicionar as colunas, e não ocultá-las.